# Return object of same type as class in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a base class with possibly many children. I have a method that needs to return the same type as the one of the class (i.e. class A returns object of type A, class B returns object of type B, etc.). Is there a good way to do it that is not declaring the same method on every class (I may need some similar methods in the future and this method could have some changes). Currently, I have a static generic method in the base class.

```
public static T FromJson<T>(string json) where T : IHttpModel =>
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, Converter.Settings);
```

This is code from quicktype.io, but I may need to change it.

Comment: _This is code from quicktype.io, but I may need to change it._ - so, does the code you've posted work for you or not? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood your task correctly, you can declare your base class as generic and declare children (if you don't have multilevel hierarchy) passing to generic parameter the type itself:

```
class Base<T> where T : IHttpModel
{
    public static T FromJson(string json)=> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, Converter.Settings);
}

class A : Base<A>, IHttpModel
{
    
}

A x = A.FromJson("");
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know such generic classes existed.

Comment: Since this is what you were looking for, why don't you mark this answer as correct? There is a check mark under the scoring of the answer, you just need to click it.